# Cannot resolve the name 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:KeyInfo' to a(n) 'element declaration' component

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

Using Eclipse in my web service project I am having problem with XML namespaces, namely I have  the following schema in my project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" blockDefault="" elementFormDefault="qualified" finalDefault="" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" version="1.0">
  <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
  <complexType abstract="true" mixed="false" name="EncryptedType">
    <sequence>
      <element minOccurs="0" name="EncryptionMethod" type="xenc:EncryptionMethodType"/>
      <element minOccurs="0" ref="ds:KeyInfo"/>
      <element ref="xenc:CipherData"/>
      <element minOccurs="0" ref="xenc:EncryptionProperties"/>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="Id" type="ID" use="optional"/>
    <attribute name="Type" type="anyURI" use="optional"/>
    <attribute name="MimeType" type="string" use="optional"/>
    <attribute name="Encoding" type="anyURI" use="optional"/>
  </complexType>
</schema>
```

and on the line with

```
<element minOccurs="0" ref="ds:KeyInfo"/>
```

I get the following error:

```
src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ds:KeyInfo' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
```

What can I do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: That would happen if the `KeyInfo` element declaration was not found. It should be in the imported `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd` (which should be loaded locally, if you have it registered in a catalog, or remotely, if you have an Internet connection).

Comment: You might need to configure a proxy so that schemas can be downloaded.

Comment: @helderdarocha I can access http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd from my machine (where tomcat is also launched so I do not see the need to configure the proxy).

Comment: I meant the proxy configuration in Eclipse for schema downloads. It would be a possible cause for this error. I pasted your schema here: [fiddle](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=bcf85318-7f83-482f-b002-aca8914618a2-xsdvalidation#.U4DrylhdWcw), commented out the unresolved `xenc` prefixes, and the XSD seems valid (click on "Check XSD Validity"). If you remove the import, or change it to an invalid URL, you will get the error you reported.